# using 2 queries for registration form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my person table

```
ID FirstName LastName Email
1    aaa       aaa     aaa
2    bbb       bbb     bbb
```

this is my members table

```
ID username password
1    aaa      aaa
2    bbb      bbb
```

this is my registration.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
        var a=document.forms["reg"]["id"].value;
        var b=document.forms["reg"]["fname"].value;
        var c=document.forms["reg"]["lname"].value;
        var d=document.forms["reg"]["username"].value;
        var e=document.forms["reg"]["password"].value;
        var f=document.forms["reg"]["email"].value;

        if ((a===null || a==="") && (b===null || b==="") && (c===null || c==="") && (d===null || d==="") && (e===null || e==="") && (f===null || f==="")) {
            alert("All Field must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if  (a===null || a==="") {
            alert("ID must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if (b===null || b==="") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if (c===null || c==="") {
            alert("Last name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if (d===null || d==="") {
            alert("Username must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if (e===null || e==="") {
            alert("Password must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        if (f===null || f==="") {
            alert("Email must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

<form name="reg" action="register_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <div align="center">
    <?php
    if (!isset($_GET['remarks'])) {$remarks=""; }
        else {$remarks=$_GET['remarks']; }

    if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="") {
        echo 'Register Here';
    }
    if ($remarks=='success') {
        echo 'Registration Success';
    }
    ?>  
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="95"><div align="right">ID:</div></td>
    <td width="171"><input type="text" name="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="95"><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
    <td width="171"><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Last Name:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Username:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Email:</div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my register_exec.php

```
 <?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "password";
    $mysql_database = "lecturer";

    $conn = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn) or die("Could not select database");
    ?>


    <?php
    session_start();

    $ID=$_POST['id'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];


    $query = ("INSERT INTO persons(ID, FirstName , LastName , Email)VALUES ('$ID' ,'$fname', '$lname', '$email')");
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO members (ID , username , password)VALUES ('$ID' , '$username' , '$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());


    if ($result && $result1) {
        header("location: Registration.php?remarks=success");
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

what i am doing is using one form and insert the data into 2 tables. i tried running it i kept getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

I am asking is it possible to do 2 queries in one php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the braces (). Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO persons(ID, FirstName , LastName , Email)VALUES ('$ID' ,'$fname', '$lname', '$email')";
$query1 = "INSERT INTO members (ID , username , password)VALUES ('$ID' , '$username' , '$password')";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can run as many queries as you want.
2. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

This is the query error, means there is some issues with the the query you are trying to run and not with running two ueries.

3  The error is coming because the correct syntax for Insert query is like this:

```
    INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Now, match your query with this syntax and try running it directly in your xampp sql, this will solve the issue.

The extra brackets in the first query,(the outer brackets) are creating problem. remove them and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Your first insert statement have a problem

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO persons(ID, FirstName , LastName , Email)VALUES ('$ID' ,'$fname', '$lname', '$email')";
$query1 = "INSERT INTO members (ID , username , password)VALUES ('$ID' , '$username' , '$password')";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule to write no of sql query in single php file means you you can write as many you would like